# TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this error in Jquery when I try to each an array of HTML elements and handle `onclick` of that element.

```js
Object.keys(collapsibles).forEach(function (key){
            $(collapsibles[key]).on('click' , function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const id = $(this).data("id");
                if (id !== _that.currentId) {
                    _that.closeCurrentOpen();
                    $(`[data-target="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('open');
                    $(`[data-img="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('arrowOpened');
                    return _that.currentId = id;
                } else {
                    return _that.closeCurrentOpen();
                }
            });
        });
```

The error is appear in this line

```
$(collapsibles[key]).on('click' , function( e ) {
```

Collapsibles value

```
var collapsibles = $('[data-behavior="collapsible"]');
```

Comment: Can you narrow down where this error occurs? Do we need all this code to get this error?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will update the post with the error line

Comment: It seems `collapsibles[key]` makes this error. What is `collapsibles`?

Comment: Collapsibles is an array of elements $('[data-behavior="collapsible"]');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below has makes error because `$(collapsibles[key])` is not a jQuery object:

```
$(collapsibles[key]).on('click' , function( e ) {//...});
```

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/9qs14dbn/3/). I simulated your code in that. You can see `collapsibles` in console that seems you didn't think it's a array that it's not suitable for you.

You can use this code instead ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/p6ck3go5/4/)):

```
$.each(collapsibles, function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
   // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, `var collapsibles = $('[data-behavior="collapsible"]');` is not an array but rather a jQuery collection object. And [you should not iterate array-like objects like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572), neither with `for … in` nor with `Object.keys(…).forEach`.

For jQuery collections, just use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), or don't use it at all but just call the `.on` method on it directly which will install the listener on all of the selected elements.

```
var collapsibles = $('[data-behavior="collapsible"]');
collapsibles.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const id = $(this).data("id");
        if (id !== _that.currentId) {
            _that.closeCurrentOpen();
            $(`[data-target="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('open');
            $(`[data-img="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('arrowOpened');
            return _that.currentId = id;
        } else {
            return _that.closeCurrentOpen();
        }
    });
});
```

```
var collapsibles = $('[data-behavior="collapsible"]');
collapsibles.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = $(this).data("id");
    if (id !== _that.currentId) {
        _that.closeCurrentOpen();
        $(`[data-target="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('open');
        $(`[data-img="${$(this).data("id")}"]`).slideDown().addClass('arrowOpened');
        return _that.currentId = id;
    } else {
        return _that.closeCurrentOpen();
    }
});
```